# how to call wp-posts data outside WordPress without getting duplicate data

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, magento

i had installed a wordpress and i want to show the posts in a page outside wordpress.(in magento page)
i had applied the query to fetch all records, but it shows me duplicate records, as i can see the duplicate posts with different id's in wp-posts table in database.
Now how can i get the single record with multiple id's once :( ???
Any idea ???

NOTE : in wordpress it is showing each post only once mean no duplicate record is showing up 2nd time, but outside wordpress it is fetching multiple instances of the same post.

i don think so any code of mine is required as it is a simple straight forward question !!!

Comment: Have you considered just working from the WordPress blog's RSS feed? Effectively, you've already got a nice public interface for grabbing your latest posts, right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress works with revisions. Each time you save a post a new revision is made. All you have to do is select the biggest revision for each post.

Comment: thats work gr8 but wat i did is that i did it with post_status="published" :)